# The green line of the LED bulb

Tags: electrical, led, bulb

one of the led bulbs in my house stopped working. I took it down and the led dots seemed fine to me.

[image]

I suspected it's connectivity issue, to me I am not sure where the green line in the picture comes from or where it should be connected to.

Below is a picture of the socket (I think). Can anyone help and tell me what might have caused that the bulb stops working?

[image]

Comment: We can see the unconnected end of the green wire in the pictures, but the other end is not shown. A picture of the other end will provide a for-sure diagnosis of what the green line does.

Comment: You "think" it's your socket???   You took it down, take a picture of your actual situation... follow @Triplefault  's advice

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 6):

"Green" in a black/white/green color scheme for wiring is usually the ground wire. It is usually connected on one end to the metal body of the fixture, and the other end is to be connected to the ground wire of the incoming power wires.

The green wire not being connected will not cause failure of the LED light. You can unscrew the screw-in adapter and screw in a regular working light bulb to see if the original ceiling fixture is still properly connected. If the light bulb lights, and replacing the screw-in adapter does not relight the LED fixture properly, then it is likely that the driver circuit inside the LED fixture that converts the incoming high-voltage power to the low-voltage power needed by the LEDs is dead. It would then be often easier to replace the whole LED fixture, rather than trying to source and replace the driver.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a retro fit situation where the green wire should be attached to the metal can of the original fixture with a sheetmetal screw. If the green wire  is not long enough it can be cut by the "eye" and another piece of wire added.
As @triplefault stated you need to verify the other connections to power and neutral as well.

Answer (score 1):

Notice how the wires from the funny socket are black-white as is normal for AC power wiring. However the wires actually going to the LED puck are yellow-white.  Those are actually DC power wires.

In between, there is a module which converts AC power to DC to run the LEDs.  This module is called an **LED Driver**.

Since LEDs are semiconductors and will probably outlive all of us, the failure point tends to be that LED driver module.  I would stick a voltmeter *set on ~100 volt DC *I say again DC* range and check voltage across the solder pads there on yellow and black.  I would expect somewhere between 30 and 40 volts DC.  If you see that, the LEDs are bad. If you don't see that, the driver or the supply to the driver is bad.

Consult with the manufacturer as to whether it's more economical to replace just the driver or the whole thing.